# Extracting values from Excel worksheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to extract values from a large Excel worksheet.

Currently, my worksheet is 1 column and lets say 2049 row data set (`Sheet1`):

```
A1
A2
...
A2049
```

From a worksheet `Sheet1`, I would like to extract data in the following format (where `A1`, `A2`, etc. are the corresponding values of those cells):

```
A1    A65   ...   A1985
A2    A66   ...   A1986
A3    A67   ...   A1987
...   ...   ...   ...
A64   A128  ...   A2049
```

I am not sure what to do here. I initially thought of using `OFFSET` or something like `=Sheet1!$A$COLUMN()*65`; however, I cannot get `OFFSET` to work the way I want it to, and the above syntax doesn't jive.

Any thoughts as to what function or syntax I need?

Comment: Please show a properly structured example of what you have and want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Non volatile [INDEX()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) with some math to get the correct rows:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,ROW(1:1)+(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*64)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the 'index' formula. It works as follows:

```
=index(lookUpColumn, row)
```

Lets say you want to import the data into Sheet2 starting in column A
    Each row is supposed to have 64 values. 
So in Column A you have values from row 1 to 64,
in column B 65 to 128

This can be calculated by `row() + (column()-1)*64`

For column `A -> column() evaluates to 1` so the term reduces to `row()`.

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!$A:$A;  ROW() + ( COLUMN() - 1 ) * 64)
```

EDIT: As Scott Craner pointed out, one may want to start importing at B or C etc. This shift can be done by changing the `1` in the formula. For `B -> 2 for c -> 3`. If the import starts in a row different from 1 a shift also needs to be included into the `row()` term

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!$A:$A;  ROW()- rowShift + ( COLUMN() - columnShift ) * 64)
```

For B2:

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!$A:$A;  ROW()- 1 + ( COLUMN() - 2) * 64)
```

Comment: I do appreciate help and corrections to my answers, as I am quiet new to the forum. So not to boost your ego, but to appreciate you involvement

Comment: Thanks for the super in depth answer! I had to give the accepted answer to Scott as he beat you to the punch. But I really appreciate you stepping through each piece of the function.

Comment: @Shinobii while I appreciate being chosen as the correct answer, if you see this as a better answer and used the formula from here, then please mark this as correct.  If you used my formula then feel free to leave it, but please do not base the selection on who came first.

Comment: @Scott Yours was the answer I used. I would never base my answer solely on speed.